# JQuery .post not working, doesn't seem to be loading post page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

This is confusing... I do not understand why this is not working... seems pretty straight forward:

```
var _t = $('#newbook-title').serialize();
var _a = $('#newbook-author').serialize();
var _u = $('#newbook-authorurl').serialize();
var _w = $('#newbook-why').serialize();

$.post("newbook.php", {t: _t, a: _a, u: _u, w: _w}, function(data) {
    alert( data.status + ',' + data.message);
});
```

Then in my newbook.php:

```
<?php
    echo "{\"status\": \"false\", \"message\":\"Made it here.\"}";
    return;
?>
```

The alert is always undefined,undefined Why? I also tried .val() instead of .serialize()

Comment: #newbook-title is this an input element or form??

Comment: First 3 are input's and #newbook-why is a textarea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because the content is not being interpreted as JSON.  Tell `$.post` what format you expect to receive:

```
$.post("newbook.php", {t: _t, a: _a, u: _u, w: _w}, function(data) {
    alert( data.status + ',' + data.message);
}, 'json');
```

Another option is to send a JSON content-type header, which jQuery will interpret for you. This is the more standards-compliant, "correct" approach:

```
// before content is output in your PHP script
header('Content-type: application/json');
```